# Apache Ignite: REPLICATION mode, counts seems inconsistent

Tags: java, ignite

I have created an Apache Ignite (V2.7) Replicated cache of 200 records. I run 2 instances of this code. When I print the `cache.localSizeLong`, it does not print 200 on both nodes. It prints something like 120 in node 1, 80 in node 2. Number varies when I rerun. Looks like it is creating a partioned cache?

Code to init cache:

```
private void initCache() {
    IgniteConfiguration configuration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    configuration.setIncludeEventTypes(EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT);//Can take multiple

    CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration("myCacheConfig");
    //https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes

    cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);

    System.out.println("Default cache mode:----" + cacheCfg.getCacheMode());
    log.debug("Default cache mode:----" + cacheCfg.getCacheMode());

    configuration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg);
    cacheCfg.setCopyOnRead(false);
    cacheCfg.setBackups(0);


    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configuration);
    cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myIgniteCache");       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `cache.localSizeLong` returns a number of entries a node is the primary for. Even though a cache is replicated it still implemented like a partitioned - each node is the primary for some data and keeps a backup copy of the rest.

Use `cache.localSizeLong(CachePeekMode.ALL)` to account both primary and backup enties.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When run on 3 servers with 500 entries, distribution seems like this.
allSize = 500, primarySize=127, backupSize=373. nearSize=0 (Svr1)

allSize = 500, primarySize=161, backupSize=339. nearSize=0 (Svr2)

allSize = 500, primarySize=212, backupSize=288. nearSize=0 (Svr3)